# How can I erase contents of array to use strcat() later?

Tags: c

I'm reading lines from a file and for part of it I've decided to read in `char` by `char`. Here's what I got:

```
char str[500];    // it has to be this size, I promise
char c;           // for reading each char
c = fgetc(fp);
while (c != '\t') // this char ends the string I'm trying to read
{
    strncat(str, &c, 1);    // strcat() didn't work
    c = fgetc(fp);  // read next char
}
```

This works fine. However, I have to read in many more lines. I've tried to reset `str` so I can use strncat() again in the same way, but I get an "Abort trap: 6" error. Here are some things I've tried (separately):

```
strcpy(str, ""); and strcpy(str, " "); // just assigns first index to '\0'
strcpy(str, 0);      // seg fault
strcpy(str, "\0"); and strcpy(str, '\0'); // same as first option
memset(str, 0, strlen(str));    // all zeroes, but Abort trap: 6
memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));    // same thing
// and (in desperation)
strcpy(str, &c + '\0');         // this is after doing strcpy(str, "");
                                // get an error
```

I'd like not to iterate over str, assigning each to null, because I have an expected string that will almost fill up the array. Thank you!

Comment: The first bug in your code is `c = fgetc(fp)` (`fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`, for a reason). The second bug is `strncat(str, ...)` (the contents of `str` are uninitialized).

Comment: strncat() takes C string as it’s second argument. You pass a pointer to char. Pointer to char may have no zero at the end. Segfault waiting to show up.

Comment: Sorry, but this is the canonical instance of [Shlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). Please read that essay.

Comment: As a second thought, Ive made a mistake statement. Your strncat is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`str[0] = 0;` is all you need -- that sticks a NUL terminator into the start of the array.  `strcpy(str, "");` has the same effect and works just as well.

Comment: I tried the `strcpy()` option, but that did not allow me to concatenate starting at index 1 (str[0]) like before. Any other ideas?

Comment: @TannerCausey These aren't "ideas". `str[0] = '\0';` is how you make `str` an empty string.